# drawing the player (a simple rectangle) with lwjgl does...nothing

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So, I wanted to program a simple game using lwjgl, however I encountered a problem even before the pre-pre-pre-alpha phase, right at the beginning.

As long as I don't have a texture for it, I wanted to draw the player just using a simple rectangle. However, my Code does nothing.

here's my openGL initialization Code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

and here's the main loop:

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            //Main loop
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            player.update();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
Display.destroy();
System.exit(0);
```

The player.update() function checks for Input and calls the draw function, which looks like this:

```
public void draw() {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f(x * World.TILE_SIZE, y * World.TILE_SIZE);
            glVertex2f(x * World.TILE_SIZE + World.TILE_SIZE, y * World.TILE_SIZE);
            glVertex2f(x * World.TILE_SIZE + World.TILE_SIZE, y * World.TILE_SIZE
                    + World.TILE_SIZE);
            glVertex2f(x * World.TILE_SIZE, y * World.TILE_SIZE + World.TILE_SIZE);
        glEnd();
}
```

To me, this looks like very simple lwjgl-code that should work without any problems, except it doesn't. When executed, it just gives me a black window, without any rectangles drawn on it. Any suggestions?

thanks in advance

-v0xelDev

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321650/swing-lwjgl-not-rendering-anything-black-screen).

Appearently, I can't draw simple coloured shapes with GL_TEXTURE_2D enabled, my openGL initialization code now looks like this:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```